# Mule/Spring ClassLoader issue when migrating to transaction-api 1.2

Tags: java, spring, mule, classloader

I am trying to migrate to transaction-api 1.2 instead of jta 1.1.

While I know I can adjust mule provided libs I can't understand why the application doesn't work by just adding transaction-api to application/lib folder. Without transaction-api everything works as expected, but with it I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.Transactional
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at org.springframework.transaction.annotation.JtaTransactionAnnotationParser.parseTransactionAnnotation(JtaTransactionAnnotationParser.java:42) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.determineTransactionAttribute(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:229) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.findTransactionAttribute(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:208) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.computeTransactionAttribute(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:397) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.getTransactionAttribute(TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:345) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

Here are some related snippers of Spring code.

`spring-data-commons`(application/lib):

```
            if (jta12Present) {
            this.annotationParsers.add(new JtaTransactionAnnotationParser());
        }
```

where:

```
        private static final boolean jta12Present = ClassUtils.isPresent("javax.transaction.Transactional",
            CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.class.getClassLoader());
```

- seems like this check is passed when transaction-api is added to the application.

`JtaTransactionAnnotationParser` is coming from mule-provided spring-tx(MULE_HOME\lib\opt). This is where it throws an exception:

```
public class JtaTransactionAnnotationParser implements TransactionAnnotationParser, Serializable {
    @Override
    public TransactionAttribute parseTransactionAnnotation(AnnotatedElement ae) {
        AnnotationAttributes attributes = AnnotatedElementUtils.getMergedAnnotationAttributes(ae, javax.transaction.Transactional.class); - ClassNotFoundException
```

Why can Spring identify Transactional in one place but cannot in another? It seems that having spring-data-commons and spring-tx in different scope can be the reason, but I don't understand why because Mule is supposed to provide a complex hierarchical ClassLoader structure and search across the whole hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, having thought about that a bit more, I think I understand it better now. As suggested in the end of my question, it is a ClassLoader-related issue. However, it is not Mule or Spring specific. It is plain old ClassLoader visibility principle:

> Visibility principle allows child class loader to see all the classes
>   loaded by parent ClassLoader, but parent class loader can not see
>   classes loaded by child.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-classloader-works-in-java.html

In my case, 2 dependent spring libraries ended up being loaded by separate ClassLoaders. That's why I strongly recommend checking your `provided` dependencies before adding any libraries with `compile` scope to the application. If ambiguities cannot be avoided, managing ClassLoader priority can be an option(parent-first vs parent-last)